# DataProvider vs Repository

Tags: c#, oop, architecture, ado.net, inversion-of-control

What is the difference between DataProvider and Repository? What logic should I use when choosing how to name my class?

Repository pattern describes class more or less like as:

```
internal interface IPersonRepository{
  public void Update(Person p);
  public void Add(Person p);
  public Person Get(int id);
  public IEnumerable<Person> GetBatch();
  public void Delete(Person p);
}
```

This is a theory, but in real life there may be other more specific methods, like `GetListPerson(int[] ids)` and so on.

But what difference with DataProvider?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, let me add some concepts:

### Repository

A [`Repository`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) is a pattern which allow you to store objects in a place, could be anything like databases, xml, txt, logs, config, etc. Some applications use a repository to implement the database persistence and it is used on the business logic layer of the application. Look this article to know more.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx

### Data Provider

A [`DataProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cd7c08(v=vs.110).aspx) is a set of components that provides connection with a database. Some dataProviders can implement only one database like [`MySql`](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/1.0.html), [`PostgreSql`](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/), [`Oracle`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) (these are not supported natively by .Net), other can connect with more databases like OleDb, since the database supports it. You can see more here on this like:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cd7c08(v=vs.110).aspx

If you want to know more, take a look at the [`ADO.NET` specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021(v=vs.71).aspx). There are some classes and concepts which is important to know like `Connection`, `Command`, `Transaction`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021(v=vs.71).aspx

### Difference between them

The difference between them is the a `Repository` which implements a database persistence using a `Data Provider` to access a database, so, the repository can encapsulates a data provider.

This is a important principle because it is nice to keep a loose coupling between the layers of your application, in other words, other layers does not want to know "how" it is persisted by the Repository, it just want to make sure it will persist and retrieve when necessary.

All the database access is provided for the `DataProvider` inside a `Repository`.

A practical sample, could be a method of the repository:

```
public Person Get(int id);
{
    Person p = null;
    using (var con = new SqlConnection("your connection string")) 
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("select * from Person where id = @id", con))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                   p = new Person();
                   p.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                   // other properties....
                }
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    return p;
}
```

Actually, you would not need to create a `PersonDataProvider`. DataProvider is ADO.NET classes which give you a database access directly, using classes that implements base interfaces from ADO.NET like `IDbConnection`, `IDbCommand`, `IDbTransaction`, etc. Now if you want to name your data access classes with a `DataProvider` sufix, no problem.

I think it is nice to have a `ORM` tool like `Entity Framework` or `NHibernate` implementing access database inside a Repository and not ADO.NET with a DataProvider and inject some dependencies of this ORM like `ISessionFactory` inside the repository's contructor.

Comment: That really good answer, but I suppose I asked my question in wrong way, I meant : What if I want to create class PersonDataProvider. From the OOP point of view what should this class do and what is difference with PersonRepository? As I understood from your answer - PersonDataProvider should provide to PersonRepository ability to communicate with storage specified inside PersonDataProvider?

Comment: @ValentynVynogradskiy I edited my anwser. In your question, `DataProvider` gives the impression that you are referencing the ADO.NET provides not a software approach.

Answer (score 0):

Repository and DataProvider are two different things.

Repository is a pattern, which you should adopt while querying Databases. (just like you mentioned in your question)

DataProvider is a .net component that retrieves data from the source you specified. More on .Net DataProviders here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7ee2dwt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx